# Symfony2 Twig Change / Replace Value

Tags: php, symfony, replace, twig

I'm new here. I'm also new in working with Symfony2.5.

I want to replace a value with another, better would be to change it via array. 
It's hard to explain - here are some code parts:

Recources/Views/register.html.twig:

```
 {% for user in list_user %}
     {{ user.Id }}
     {{ user.isAdmin }}
     {{ user.isActive }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Here I generate the array to send to register.html.twig which looks like this:

Controller/AccountController.php

```
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:User')
        ->findAll();

    return $this->render(
        'SeotoolMainBundle:Account:register.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView(), 'list_user' => $user)
    );
```

It correctly outputs for isAdmin and isActive 0 or 1. Now I want to replace this output with for example isActive = 1 should Output "Active", isActive = 0 shut Output "Not active".
I hope you understand what I mean and can help me find the correct way to do this.

Thank you guys,
kind regards,

Marvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use an "if"?

```
{% for user in list_user %}
 {{ user.Id }}
 {{ user.isAdmin }}
 {% if user.isActive %}
   Active
 {% else %}
   Inactive
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can also use the ternary operator, which is more compact.

```
{% for user in list_user %}
 {{ user.Id }}
 {{ user.isAdmin }}
 {{ user.isActive ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I tried the whole time user.isActive == 1 - but with your solution it works perfect. What would it look like when isActive would be a string, for example active_yes and active_no - and i want to check, wich one it is, therfor user.isActive == "active_yes" doesn't work for me?! Thank you so far!! :-)

Comment: Both _if_ and _ternary operator_ require a boolean expression. Given that `user.isActive == 'active_yes'` is a valid boolean expression, it should work indeed, in place of `user.isActive` only. :)

Comment: Yep - strange...don't know why mine did not worked some minutes ago...Thank you - now all is working perfect! Thanks :)